# Accessing and modifying the same singleton from different projects in the same solution

Tags: c#

I have a singleton which looks something like this:

```
public sealed class Singleton
{
    private static readonly Lazy<Singleton> lazy =
        new Lazy<Singleton>(() => new Singleton());

    public static Singleton Instance { get { return lazy.Value; } }

    private Singleton()
    {
    }

    public int field1 { get; set; }
    public string field2 { get; set; }
}
```

For reference, I took it from [here](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx) (the sixth version).

This singleton has a few fields as shown in the example and my solution has 2 projects. `field1` is being modified by project 1 and `field2` is being modified by project 2. project1 is an API, and project2 is a console app that calls this API. The Singleton is used to store log data from both projects in the same place.

The issue is that by the time project 2 accesses `field2`, `field1` is back to its default value, as if the singleton had been instantiated again. I've tried other examples in the referenced website above with locking but that hasn't worked. I would like `field1` to have the value it was assigned by project 1 by the time my program accesses `field2` in project 2.

Comment: What are project1 and project2? Separate executables? Something else? Singletons aren’t something that are existing only one in the universe, they exist one per process.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen project1 is an API, and project2 is a console app that calls this API. The Singleton is used to store log data from both projects in the same place.

Comment: So you're running project2 as a console app, and it references and calls methods in project1 directly (i.e., in the same process)? And this Singleton is in project1?

Comment: @JoeSewell yes exactly although I think they are just 2 different processes and that's why I can't get to the singleton

Comment: I wouldn't be so sure that just because this isn't working you necessarily have two processes without intending to. Can you show how your console app calls the API?

Comment: @JoeSewell I am using ServiceStack and just making simple HTTP requests using `JsonServiceClient`. I might be wrong but what makes me think it's 2 different processes is that whenever I start the API, Chrome opens up, and then I have to start a separate instance of the console app to call the API.

Comment: If you are making HTTP requests to the API, then setup the singleton in the api's root at startup. All access to the singleton will be through the API's methods. The singleton is abstracted away from your console app and only makes calls through the API. If you need to set field2 from the console app -- make a call through the API to do so.

Comment: @jgozal Ah, I see. Yes, if you're using a client-server model (where the console app is the client, and the API is the server), then yes, you have multiple processes and thus multiple app domains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the projects you're referring are executing in different AppDomains. Maybe even different processes at all. Statics are scoped by application domains, so referring to the singleton from a different AppDomain would obviously result in new static instance to be created.

Comment: I understand. Any way to work around this? perhaps with a different solution that's not a singleton?

Comment: Can you please share more details about your setup? Would definitely be happy to help

Comment: @jgozal a database... a file... since this is an API try asking for the singleton's data in the console app.

Comment: @Jasen i guess that would be the way to go, just passing it through the API

Comment: @jgozal, if you're running within a single process, and still need to maintain a common state, you have two options: 1. Use external store (file, db, ...) and 2. Consider Marshalling - and work with proxy of the static object...

Comment: There are some ways for Interprocess Communications. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365574.aspx Pipes/Networking are among the more common ones.